# how homogeneity is calculated?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to find an image is homogeneous in matlab. my image contains 5 coins.I used the function improfile to create the intensity but I don't know how to identify the homogeneous circle. 
homogeneity is considered using the intensity inside the coin.
how to code it

```
close all;clear all;
I = imread('coins.png');
bw =( im2bw(I, graythresh(I)));
[L N]= bwlabel(bw);
ele=find(L==3);
Im1=zeros([size(I,1) size(I,2)]);
Im1(ele)=1;
figure,imshow(Im1)
ML=I; ML(Im1==0)= 0; figure, imshow(ML);
figure,imhist(ML(Im1==1))
st = regionprops(L,I,'PixelValues'); 
pv = st(3).PixelValues;
figure, imhist(pv)
```

I plot the histogram.but I dont know how to proceed

Standard deviation of histogram and normal histogram is plotting as same
[image]
[image]

Comment: From a dictionary "the quality or state of being all the same or all of the same kind.". I am not sure what is your mathematical definition of it...

Comment: Lookup image segmentation.

Comment: I guess... you're looking for a circle that looks like a circle?

Comment: @user1234: as usual, the question would be much easier to understand with a picture.

Comment: I assume if they are "the same" as I said in the beggining.

Comment: @user1234: please don't spit a file name at me.

Comment: We dont write code for you, this is not what stackoverlfow is for.

Comment: @Ander Biguri     edited with code i know pls unhold question

Comment: @MateenUlhaq edited with code i know pls unhold question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw homogeneity criteria from the histogram of gray-levels or the histogram of gradient intensities.

A low dispersion (small variance) reveals a quasi-constant lightness, but is sensitive to smooth variations.

A low gradient average reveals a lack of detail, but is sensitive to texture/noise.

Comment: @user1234: no Sir.

Comment: @user1234: I suggest to lookup "matlab histogram variance"

Comment: @user1234: I have done enough for you, sorry.

Comment: sir i had plotted the standard deviation of histogram and normal histogram.both are looking same.can you check the updated code. Is the coin homogeneous?